# Swift ui radar chart

Tags: swift, swiftui, diagram, radar-chart

Result final:

[image]

My result:

[image]

how can i do so to get the same result?

Code:

```
//
//  RadarChartView.swift
//  codeTutorial_radarChart
//
//  Created by Christopher Guirguis on 4/4/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Christopher Guirguis. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI


let dimensions = [
    Ray(maxVal: 100, rayCase: .Base),
    Ray(maxVal: 100, rayCase: .Content),
    Ray(maxVal: 100, rayCase: .SpeedWeb),
    Ray(maxVal: 100, rayCase: .SpeedMobile),
    Ray(maxVal: 100, rayCase: .Social)
]

let data = [
    DataPoint(base: 58.9, content: 20.3, speedweb: 91, speedmobile: 56.01, social: 55.6, color: .blue),
]


enum RayCase:String, CaseIterable {
    case Base = "Base"
    case Content = "Content"
    case SpeedWeb = "SpeedWeb"
    case SpeedMobile = "SpeedMobile"
    case Social = "Social"
}

struct DataPoint:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var entrys:[RayEntry]
    var color:Color
    
    init(base:Double, content:Double, speedweb:Double, speedmobile:Double, social:Double, color:Color){
        self.entrys = [
            RayEntry(rayCase: .Base, value: base),
            RayEntry(rayCase: .Content, value: content),
            RayEntry(rayCase: .SpeedWeb, value: speedweb),
            RayEntry(rayCase: .SpeedMobile, value: speedmobile),
            RayEntry(rayCase: .Social, value: social)
        ]
        self.color = color
    }
}

struct Ray:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var maxVal:Double
    var rayCase:RayCase
    init(maxVal:Double, rayCase:RayCase) {
        self.rayCase = rayCase
        self.name = rayCase.rawValue
        self.maxVal = maxVal
        
    }
}

struct RayEntry{
    var rayCase:RayCase
    var value:Double
}

func deg2rad(_ number: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return number * .pi / 180
}

func radAngle_fromFraction(numerator:Int, denominator: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return deg2rad(360 * (CGFloat((numerator))/CGFloat(denominator)))
}

func degAngle_fromFraction(numerator:Int, denominator: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 360 * (CGFloat((numerator))/CGFloat(denominator))
    
}

struct RadarChartView: View {
    
    var MainColor:Color
    var SubtleColor:Color
    var center:CGPoint
    var labelWidth:CGFloat = 70
    var width:CGFloat
    var quantity_incrementalDividers:Int
    var dimensions:[Ray]
    var data:[DataPoint]
    
    init(width: CGFloat, MainColor:Color, SubtleColor:Color, quantity_incrementalDividers:Int, dimensions:[Ray], data:[DataPoint]) {
        self.width = width
        self.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: width/2)
        self.MainColor = MainColor
        self.SubtleColor = SubtleColor
        self.quantity_incrementalDividers = quantity_incrementalDividers
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.data = data
    }
    
    @State var showLabels = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            //Main Spokes
            Path { path in
                
                
                for i in 0..<self.dimensions.count {
                    let angle = radAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i, denominator: self.dimensions.count)
                    let x = (self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth))/2 * cos(angle)
                    let y = (self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth))/2 * sin(angle)
                    path.move(to: center)
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + x, y: center.y + y))
                }
                
            }
            .stroke(self.MainColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            //Labels
            ForEach(0..<self.dimensions.count){i in
                
                Text(self.dimensions[i].rayCase.rawValue)
                    
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .foregroundColor(self.SubtleColor)
                    .frame(width:self.labelWidth, height:10)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(
                        (degAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i, denominator: self.dimensions.count) > 90 && degAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i, denominator: self.dimensions.count) < 270) ? 180 : 0
                        ))
                    
                    
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .offset(x: (self.width - (50))/2)
                    .rotationEffect(.radians(
                        Double(radAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i, denominator: self.dimensions.count)
                    )))
            }
            //Outer Border
            Path { path in
                
                for i in 0..<self.dimensions.count + 1 {
                    let angle = radAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i, denominator: self.dimensions.count)
                    
                    let x = (self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth))/2 * cos(angle)
                    let y = (self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth))/2 * sin(angle)
                    if i == 0 {
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + x, y: center.y + y))
                    } else {
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + x, y: center.y + y))
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
            .stroke(self.MainColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            //Incremental Dividers
            ForEach(0..<self.quantity_incrementalDividers){j in
                Path { path in
                    
                    
                    for i in 0..<self.dimensions.count + 1 {
                        let angle = radAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i, denominator: self.dimensions.count)
                        let size = ((self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth))/2) * (CGFloat(j + 1)/CGFloat(self.quantity_incrementalDividers + 1))
                        
                        let x = size * cos(angle)
                        let y = size * sin(angle)
                        print(size)
                        print((self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth)))
                        print("\(x) -- \(y)")
                        if i == 0 {
                            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + x, y: self.center.y + y))
                        } else {
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + x, y: self.center.y + y))
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .stroke(self.SubtleColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                
                
            }
            
            //Data Polygons
            ForEach(0..<self.data.count){j -> AnyView in
                //Create the path
                let path = Path { path in
                    
                    
                    for i in 0..<self.dimensions.count + 1 {
                        let thisDimension = self.dimensions[i == self.dimensions.count ? 0 : i]
                        let maxVal = thisDimension.maxVal
                        let dataPointVal:Double = {
                            
                            for DataPointRay in self.data[j].entrys {
                                if thisDimension.rayCase == DataPointRay.rayCase {
                                    return DataPointRay.value
                                }
                            }
                            return 0
                        }()
                        let angle = radAngle_fromFraction(numerator: i == self.dimensions.count ? 0 : i, denominator: self.dimensions.count)
                        let size = ((self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth))/2) * (CGFloat(dataPointVal)/CGFloat(maxVal))
                        
                        
                        let x = size * cos(angle)
                        let y = size * sin(angle)
                        print(size)
                        print((self.width - (50 + self.labelWidth)))
                        print("\(x) -- \(y)")
                        if i == 0 {
                            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + x, y: self.center.y + y))
                        } else {
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + x, y: self.center.y + y))
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                //Stroke and Fill
                return AnyView(
                    ZStack{
                        path
                            .stroke(self.data[j].color, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.5, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                        path
                            .foregroundColor(self.data[j].color).opacity(0.2)
                    }
                )
                
                
            }
            
        }.frame(width:width, height:width)
    }
}



struct RadarChartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
                Text("Final evaluation")
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                RadarChartView(
                    width: 370,
                    MainColor: Color.init(white: 0.8),
                    SubtleColor: Color.init(white: 0.6),
                    quantity_incrementalDividers: 10,
                    dimensions: dimensions,
                    data: data
                )
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it: rotation, labels?

Comment: @Asperi: Let's start with the rotation of the graph, I would like the content of the graph that is the tip, perhaps towards the top in the center where its tip is located.